# toSpatialDatabaseRecordList produce a NullPointerException

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-spatial

We encountered a problem using java plugin for neo4j. Until today we had no problem to use the toSpatialDatabaseRecordList method on GeoPipeline. We have just made some bugs corrections and now we get a NullPointerException on the method call.

Here is the code :

```
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    geoPoints = GeoPipeline
        .startNearestNeighborLatLonSearch(layer, point, radius)
        .toSpatialDatabaseRecordList();
    tx.success();
}
```

[EDIT] Here is the full stack :

```
Unable to search trips [500]:
Headers: Array
(
    [Content-Type] =>  application/json; charset=UTF-8; stream=true
    [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] =>  *
    [Server] =>  Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)
)
Body: Array
(
    [exception] => NullPointerException
    [fullname] => java.lang.NullPointerException
    [stacktrace] => Array
        (
            [0] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.rtree.filter.AbstractSearchEnvelopeIntersection.needsToVisit(AbstractSearchEnvelopeIntersection.java:38)
            [1] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.rtree.RTreeIndex$SearchEvaluator.checkPosition(RTreeIndex.java:268)
            [2] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.rtree.RTreeIndex$SearchEvaluator.isStopNode(RTreeIndex.java:283)
            [3] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.OldTraverserWrapper$Pruner.evaluate(OldTraverserWrapper.java:260)
            [4] => org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Evaluator$AsPathEvaluator.evaluate(Evaluator.java:69)
            [5] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MultiEvaluator.evaluate(MultiEvaluator.java:62)
            [6] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.evaluate(MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.java:59)
            [7] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.evaluate(TraversalBranchImpl.java:125)
            [8] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.initialize(TraversalBranchImpl.java:130)
            [9] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.next(TraversalBranchImpl.java:151)
            [10] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchWithState.next(TraversalBranchWithState.java:32)
            [11] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.StartNodeTraversalBranch.next(StartNodeTraversalBranch.java:50)
            [12] => org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.PreorderDepthFirstSelector.next(PreorderDepthFirstSelector.java:49)
            [13] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.java:68)
            [14] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.java:35)
            [15] => org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
            [16] => org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
            [17] => org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.next(PrefetchingIterator.java:75)
            [18] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.OldTraverserWrapper$TraverserImpl.next(OldTraverserWrapper.java:86)
            [19] => org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.OldTraverserWrapper$TraverserImpl.next(OldTraverserWrapper.java:47)
            [20] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.filter.SearchRecords.next(SearchRecords.java:53)
            [21] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.filter.SearchRecords.next(SearchRecords.java:29)
            [22] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.GeoPipeline$1.next(GeoPipeline.java:134)
            [23] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.GeoPipeline$1.next(GeoPipeline.java:126)
            [24] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.impl.LastElementIterator.next(LastElementIterator.java:19)
            [25] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.impl.IdentityPipe.processNextStart(IdentityPipe.java:18)
            [26] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.impl.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:72)
            [27] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.AbstractGeoPipe.processNextStart(AbstractGeoPipe.java:49)
            [28] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.AbstractGeoPipe.processNextStart(AbstractGeoPipe.java:31)
            [29] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.impl.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:72)
            [30] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.AbstractGeoPipe.processNextStart(AbstractGeoPipe.java:49)
            [31] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.AbstractGeoPipe.processNextStart(AbstractGeoPipe.java:31)
            [32] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.impl.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:72)
            [33] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.impl.Pipeline.next(Pipeline.java:113)
            [34] => org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.GeoPipeline.toSpatialDatabaseRecordList(GeoPipeline.java:998)
            [35] => org.neo4j.ecolutis.server.plugins.WayPointsSearcher.getWayPointsSimpleWay(WayPointsSearcher.java:80)
            [36] => org.neo4j.ecolutis.server.plugins.WayPointsSearcher.getWayPoints(WayPointsSearcher.java:52)
            [37] => org.neo4j.ecolutis.server.plugins.SearchTrips.searchTrips(SearchTrips.java:76)
            [38] => java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            [39] => org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)
            [40] => org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:159)
            [41] => org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)
            [42] => org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)
            [43] => java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            [44] => org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)
            [45] => java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        )

)
```

Have you some idea about how to deal with this issue ? Is that a data problem ?

Regards,

nO

Comment: Please share the full NPE stacktrace"

Comment: What does your data look like? Did you perhaps create some geospatial structure and then delete parts of it?